# How do smooth a faceted model that has been imported?

Tags: modeling

I have imported an Obj of an arrow and it's rather faceted. How can I make it smoother (I assume split it into more faces?) and look as expected?

Edit: I want the mesh to actually be smoother (rather than smooth shading that just makes it look smooth) as I will be exporting it.

I have quite a lot of these to do, so if anyone could point me in the direction of a video/tutorial I can follow I would appreciate it.

[image: faceted arrow]

Comment: right click > Shade Smooth and also you can enable the Auto Smooth option in the Object Data panel > Normals, what does it give?

Comment: Isn't that just cossmetic? I want the mesh itself to be smoothed as I will be exporting it out

Comment: in that case apply a Subdivision Surface modifier, but first remove the Mark Sharp with a Ctrl E > Clear Sharp and bevel the angles with a Ctrl B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, then remove the *Mark Sharp* with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Mark Sharp* and instead bevel with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> in order to keep the angles sharp. When you're good apply the *Subdivision Surface* (but first always keep a version with the modifier non-applied):

[image]

Edit: Your topology is bad, you have edges overlapping, select this edge and dissolve it (make sure that you select the bad edge and not another one, and do the same on the side underneath):

[image]

Create this topology:

[image]

Also collapse the 2 edges of the tip (<kbd>X</kbd>):

[image]

Now select all the edges that you want to keep sharp:

[image]

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel:

[image]

Shade smooth, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, I'm struggling to get anything remotely nice out of it. I recall in Maya there is a smooth tool that in about 2 clicks does exactly what I am after. I am clearly missing something here as it seems like a rather fundamental thing to want to do

Comment: Where are you struggling? Have you done what I recommend? It's rather simple...

Comment: I'm not sure how to show/explain, but I can't get it to keep the edges as one would want. All i want is the cylindrical faces to be smoother, the edges should remain hard/as is. I'm happy to admin I'm doing something stupid, here's the obj if you would be so kind to try yourself      https://justbeamit.com/cbrb7

Comment: it says "sorry, this download link no longer exists". As I said you need to create a bevel all along these edges, or give your object a Bevel modifier before the Subdivision Surface modifier and apply. But please share again

Comment: Have you tried adding a bevel modifier before the subdivision surface modifier so you get a smooth shape while retaining some sharper edges

Comment: Thanks for everyones help. I have tried the bevel modifier and following @moonBoots instructions and the geometry just looks worse. Not sure what happened to the original link heres another to that arrow  https://ufile.io/bfhw8cca

Comment: Your object has bad topology, please see my edit

Comment: Thanks, It is something I got of turbo squid. Unfortunately, I have about 30 of these to do! I have not tried your approach, but given your detailed answer, I think it all seems logical so marking it as solved. Thank you for all your help

Comment: As you said, if you simply Shade Smooth it won't smooth the shape, only the shading, it may be enough for some of your objects though. That said, what I see with your arrow is that you need to Clear Custom Split Normals Data in the Object Data panel > Geometry, otherwise you may have bad shading with a simple Shade Smooth.

Comment: Yes I guess when you purchase these 3D objects you can't be sure that the topology will be correct...